# Different click event actions for marker in google maps api

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3

I have a set of a maps activity with a marker click method. The markers are added from the database and open a new `Activity` when clicked. The issue i am having is separating the current location to have a different click event.

I have tried creating a 2nd marker (marker2) and use that but i do not think i am handling this correctly. The code below is my attempt to resolve it with `Hashmap` but i cant seem to get it right.

```
//This is the onclick method- i tried using an if statment if the value is not there to call the second marker. 
     mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                String venueID = mMarkerMap.get(marker.getId());
                String venueName = marker.getTitle();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, viewbeverageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(VENUE_NAME, venueName);
                intent.putExtra(VENUE_ID, venueID);
                startActivity(intent);

                if(venueID == null)
                {
                    onMarkerClick2(marker2);
                }

                return false;
            }

            public boolean onMarkerClick2(Marker marker2) {

                mMap2.getClass();

                return false;
            }
        });


//This is the location listener for the current location
 public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return false;
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

        public void onLocationChanged (Location loc){
            if (loc != null){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                       "Current Location : Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() +
                                " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                LatLng p = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
                Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = null;

                String add = "";
                try {
                       //String placeName = "YOU ARE HERE";
                    addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(),1);
                    Address address = addresses.get(0);

                    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                            add += address.getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                       // mMap2.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(p).title("You Are Here"));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mMap2.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(p)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
                        .title("YOU ARE HERE  ")
                        .snippet(KEY + "Population: 4,137,400"));
               // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(p).title("YOU ARE HERE"));
                mMap2.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(p, 12.0f));
            }
        }
```

When i click on the current location it is trying to find the details from the database the same as the rest but no succeeding and causing the app to crash and say beer app keeps stopping. the on click section reaches the esle statement but i just need to know how to some out of that mehtod and continue to the 2nd click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set tag like this :

```
Marker marker = new Marker() ;
marker.setTag(position);// you can give ArrayList position and then get in on marker click method.
```